# How Do I Put JLabel and JTextField on top of Image?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage, jtextfield

I am trying to create a game where I have a background image and text on top of that in the form of `JLabel`s. How would I go about doing that?

The main reason I'm doing this is so that I can have 2 different text areas with different font sizes. Using `g.drawString()` will only let you use 1 text size for the whole thing.

Here is my code so far:

```
package com.cgp.buildtown;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Intro extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Thread thread;
    private BufferedImage bg;
    private Font font;

    public Intro() {
        super();
        loadImages();
        setFont(loadFont(50f));
    }

    private Font loadFont(Float f) {
        try {
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res/komikatext.ttf"));
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(font);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return font.deriveFont(f);
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("res/introbg.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't override `paint()` in a `JPanel`.  Use `paintComponent()`. 2. To make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), add a `main(String[])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way.

[image: Intro. screen]

But of course that is merely a version hacked out of your own code/ specs.  For a much better implementation of the same idea, see this [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Intro extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Thread thread;
    private BufferedImage bg;
    private String html =
        "<html><body style='color: yellow;'>" +
        "<h1>Game</h1>" +
        "<p>Welcome to the Game!";

    public Intro() {
        super();
        loadImages();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40,40,40,40));
        add(new JLabel(html), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JTextField("..enter name"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg");
            bg = ImageIO.read(url);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Intro());
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem. The JLabel doesn't like my custom font. It's loading correctly, because it works with g.drawString().

Comment: *"It's loading correctly"*  It does not load correctly here, and would not load correctly on the machines of your end user (it also, because of that, would not work in an SSCCE!).  At time of deployment, put the font in a Jar and get an URL using `this.getClass().getResource("/res/komikatext.ttf");`.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that at compiling time, but that doesn't solve the problem that the JLabel isn't using the font I want.

Comment: It is necessary to set the font in the HTML styles.  Alternately, **don't** use HTML and call [`JLabel.setFont(Font)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29).

Answer (score -2):

first load the background image then opaque its property then add the other components on it.

Comment: *"then opaque its property"*  Can you link to this 'property' in the JavaDocs?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html here setOpaque(boolean isOpaque) 
          If true the component paints every pixel within its bounds.

Comment: I understand now.  Any chance of an edit? 1) to change *"then opaque its property"* to *"then opaque the `JComponent` property"* and 2) an update of that link from an obsolete JRE to point to the Java 7 docs at [JComponent.setOpaque(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque%28boolean%29)?