# How can I use a Jtextfield on top of a Jlabel?

Tags: java, jframe

i created this code to do a Q&A thing using an icon as background:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class test
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel bg;
    private Jbutton button1;
    private ImageIcon icon;
    private JTextField tf;
    public test(){
        run();
    }
    public void run(){
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);

        icon = new ImageIcon("My_Path");
        bg = new JLabel(icon);
        bg.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tf = new JTextField("text field",100);
        tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tf);

        button1 = new JButton("Check!");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                /*action*/
            }
        });

        frame.add(bg);

        label = new JLabel("text");
        bg.add(label);
        bg.add(button1);
    } 
    public void main(String[] args){
        new test();
    }
```

and for some reason the text field is 'blocking' the label bg and make it move.
how can i make the text field 'go over' the icon in the label bg ?

Comment: You would likely either set a textfield position property on the text-field, or nest it in the label

Comment: What do you mean by `blocking`? If you want a JTextField on top of an image, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556626/how-do-i-put-jlabel-and-jtextfield-on-top-of-image

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify a layout in order to place the elements in the way you want them. For example: you can set layout to null

frame.setLayout(null);

and the specify the coordinates of the objects with setBounds(x, x, x, x), or use any other layout, all depends on how you need them...

check this for more reference...

http://www.javatpoint.com/java-layout-manager

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom JPanel and override its paintComponent method, but it’s generally easier to just use an [OverlayLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html):

```
JComponent fields = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
fields.setOpaque(false);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_LEADING;
fields.add(tf, gbc);
gbc.insets.top = 6;
fields.add(label, gbc);
fields.add(button1, gbc);

fields.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
fields.setAlignmentY(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
bg.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
bg.setAlignmentY(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

JPanel overlay = new JPanel();
overlay.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(overlay));
overlay.add(fields);
overlay.add(bg);

frame.getContentPane().add(overlay);
```

Note that you should call `frame.setVisible(true)` *after* adding components to the JFrame.